# Force Cmake to use system include path first

Tags: unit-testing, cmake, googletest

Im tring to build sources for unit testing with are part of bigger project.

Im using CmakeList inside which i point to directories where include headers are placed.

Somehow side by side with proper include header is placed string.h header made by someone with is causing problems.

How can i force Cmake to use string.h from /user/include first instead string.h from someModule/include?

When i delete string.h from someModule/include everything builds successfully.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CMake: ordering of include directories (How to mix system- and user-based include paths?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7752609/cmake-ordering-of-include-directories-how-to-mix-system-and-user-based-includ)

Comment: Unfortunatelly not, im using target_include_directories like so: 
target_include_directories(${MODULE} PRIVATE ${PRIVATE_INCLUDE_DIRS}). As I userstand it should add those paths after system dirs

Comment: Can you please post example code that shows how the `string.h` header is included? Specifically, are you using `#include <string.h>` or `#include "string.h"`? I'm assuming this is a program written in C?

Comment: It is included like so: #include <string.h>, it is very weird that gcc uses string.h from someModule/include instead /usr/include

Comment: As the answers in my linked post suggest, you could also include change the include directory for `someModule` to allow you to include this `string.h` file with `#include <someModule/include/string.h>`, to remove the ambiguity for the compiler. This is a safer approach; see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3126467/3987854).