# CMake searches include files in system directories first

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, include

I have [a library](https://github.com/tigertv/BeeNum) that uses CMake as a building system. It builds for ubuntu, [but not for windows](https://github.com/tigertv/Bint/actions/runs/405768688).
The issue happens because on windows it searches 'Math.h' in system directories first, but not in the project's 'include' directory.
I've tried to rename all 'Math' files and class by 'Math2' and [it works great](https://github.com/tigertv/Bint/actions/runs/405609045). But I don't want to rename the class and files.
What do I have to do?

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.10)

project (Bint
    VERSION "0.1.0"
    DESCRIPTION "Bint is an arbitrary-precision arithmetic library."
    LANGUAGES CXX
)

enable_testing()

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
if(MSVC)
    #add_compile_options(/Wall)
else()
    add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -pedantic)
endif()

include_directories(BEFORE ./include)

set(BINT_SRC src/Bint.cpp)
set(MATH_SRC src/Math.cpp)
add_library(shareobjects OBJECT ${BINT_SRC} ${MATH_SRC})

add_executable(test-main-fast tests/main.cpp ${BINT_SRC} ${MATH_SRC})
set_target_properties(test-main-fast PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS -Ofast)
add_test(NAME tst-main-fast COMMAND ./test-main-fast)

aux_source_directory(tests TESTS)
foreach(tstfile ${TESTS})
    string(REGEX MATCH "\/(.*)\\.[^.]*$" dummy ${tstfile})
    add_executable(test-${CMAKE_MATCH_1} ${tstfile} $<TARGET_OBJECTS:shareobjects>)
    add_test(NAME tst-${CMAKE_MATCH_1} COMMAND ./test-${CMAKE_MATCH_1})
endforeach()

add_library(Bint SHARED ${BINT_SRC} ${MATH_SRC})
set_target_properties(test-main-fast PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS -Ofast)

add_library(Bint_static STATIC $<TARGET_OBJECTS:shareobjects>)
set_target_properties(Bint_static PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME Bint)
```

Comment: It appears a bit stupid to me to name a file `math.h` or `Math.h` if it's not _the_ `math.h` (of the C standard library)... (Hopefully, this is not a hint about the general quality of this library.) ;-)

Comment: @Scheff, It has a namespace, so this is not a problem I suppose.

Comment: Well, a `namespace` is something which is considered by the C++ compiler. That still doesn't help for file names (as you already noticed).

Comment: @Scheff, what would be if tomorrow somebody adds a class in std library that has name(files) as in your project?

Comment: It is a bad practice to name a custom header file in the same way as one in the C standard library. Also, on Windows file names a **case-insensitive**, so `Math.h` is treated as `math.h`. The preferable approach is to **rename** the header. "what would be if tomorrow somebody adds a class in std library that have name(files) as in your project?" - Do not give your headers "common" names like `strings.h` or `vars.h`. Note, that you may either add the prefix to your header (`mylib_strings.h`) or place the header into the subdirectory (so it will be included via `#include <mylib/strings.h>`).

Comment: There is a very simple trick concerning this: C++ standard header doesn't have a suffix but my own header (still) always have a `.h`. Furthermore, I name my files with prefixes which make such a collision unlikely. The C++ header doesn't arise suddenly but should only do so with a change of the standard. In case, you have to fix your legacy code if you want to port it to an new standard.

Comment: @Scheff, I've used `include "Math.h"` with `.h`, so it doesn't help.

Comment: You may find other SO questions about header names which conflicts with the standard. See e,g, that one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125090/string-h-conflicting-with-my-own-string-h.

Comment: @Scheff said Math.h would not help on windows because of the case insensitivity of the file system.

Comment: @drescherjm, I replaced Math.h by math.h, and it works on ubuntu but not on  windows.

Comment: That makes sense. linux has case sensitive (some but not all) file systems while windows has case insensitive but case preserving.  Remember what case insensitive means. For case insensitive when searching for "Math.h" if it finds "math.h" it will accept that as being the file it wants.

Comment: I know about case sensitivity in Windows, on ubuntu it works in two cases(upper and lower), but not on windows(also two cases).

Comment: ***ubuntu it works in two cases(upper and lower),*** That is because your file system on ubuntu is case sensitive meaning "Math.h" and "math.h" are seen as 2 different files. You can even put them in the same folder. Just rename the file to avoid the issue.

Comment: @drescherjm, Yes, I suppose I have to do that, or use "<>".

Comment: ... S o l v e d